# pikaday.js script not working in Electron or NW.js

Tags: javascript, pikaday

I am using the [pikaday.js](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) in a webform. It works great in a normal browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.), but it doesn't load defaults in Electron or NW.js. The author says it has nothing to do with him, so I am posting this here to see if anyone else knows a fix?

The pikaday always return dates in the "Wed June 17, 2015" format in Electron and NW.js. I have even changed the default in the original code to be "06/17/2015", but it will not do it. HELP!

Comment: **BTW:** I think I figured out part of the problem. It doesn't think Moment.js is loaded. But, I load Moment.js just before Pikaday.js. It must have something to do with the way it check for Moment.js.